# Remove Shut Down from Login Window

Tags: macos

Is there a way to remove the Shut Down option from the login window on Mac OS X (10.11.x) while preserving the ability to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the `defaults write` command is, but [Mac Pilot](http://www.koingosw.com/products/macpilot/) can do this by setting this:

[image]

I just confirmed it works in 10.11.5 without needing a reboot.

**Update**

I figured out the `defaults write`:

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow ShutDownDisabled -bool true`

Afterwards, the command

`sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow ShutDownDisabled`

should equal `1`.

Comment: I used the defaults write option and it worked!!!

Answer (score 5):

In **Terminal** type this:
`defaults write com.apple.loginwindow ShutDownDisabled -true` to hide the *Shutdown* option.

To restore it again, type:
`defaults write com.apple.loginwindow ShutDownDisabled -false`

Comment: Just tested this on Mac OS X 10.11.5 with and without sudo but it didn't remove the Shut Down option on the login window. Note: The Mac was indeed rebooted.